# PrimeFaces Push from non Ajax call

Tags: ajax, primefaces, push

I'm using primefaces 3.1, and I want to use the PrimeFaces Push.

I want to make a push from a **non** ajax call, but off course cannot do it with

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().push(channel, msg)
```

because it returns null.

Can I make a push using something else ? because I need to make it from a non ajax call.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In primefaces forums, they told me that this could not be possible with that version of primerfaces. 
In theory, it will be possible in primefaces 3.4